# Why don't answer edits count toward editing badges?

Tags: discussion, edits, edit-badges

There are [several queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=strunk) on the data explorer site that show your progress toward the various editing badges like Editor, Strunk & White, and Copy Editor. Based on most of these queries and my own results, it seems like the badges are filtering on a post type of "question", so that editing other users' answers does not contribute toward these badges.

I'm curious about why the design team would exclude answer edits. Was there a technical problem, or did they really think that question editing was much more important than answer editing?

Comment: Answer edits do count. It's the queries that are wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on my comment:

Answer edits do count towards the editing badges. If the queries don't reflect that then the queries are wrong.

Also the queries can only check the **last editor** of a post and so will under-report the number of edits you have made if someone else edited the same post **after** you.

Comment: Any idea if the last editor of a post reflects tag changes? That's the only explanation I can think of, because the data explorer queries show me with more than 100 edits on Stack Overflow if I include answer and question edits. I did a lot of retagging in the early days, so that might be confusing the queries.

Comment: @Don - pure tag edits don't count. See [Jeff's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges) to a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

[Progress Towards Editor Badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges) selects all questions

```
WHERE
    (PostTypeId = 1 OR PostTypeId = 2)
```

... and since [PostTypeId of 1 means questions and 2 means answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71240/regarding-the-stack-overflow-db-schema/71241#71241), this seems correct to me.

[Strunk & White and Copy Editor Progress](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/381/strunk-white-and-copy-editor-progress), however, incorrectly requires a PostTypeId of 1.

As ChrisF mentioned, queries on data.stackexchange.com only have access to the public data dumps, so they can only check the last editor.